# Mulesoft - Need help in creating cron expression for Mule scheduler job application

Tags: cron, mule4

I need help in creating cron expression for Mule scheduler job.

**Scenario** : Job should run in every month from 3rd day to 6th day for every 2 hours(intra day) and those days should be working days(Monday to Friday only).

I tried below cron expression in cronMaker : 0 0 7-20/2 3-5 * Mon-Fri *
Here i am getting error for this above expression.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the same cron expression in an actual Mule application -I used Mule runtime 4.3- using a [Scheduler](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/scheduler-concept) source you will get the following error:

```
Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
```

This is a limitation of the Quartz library that the Scheduler uses in its implementation. This means it is not possible to use that kind of cron expression in a Mule Scheduler, or a Quartz Java application.

Likely [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com) has the same limitation but it is not showing the full error message.

Updated:
You can avoid the limitation by using only one of the conditions, for example day-of-month (it will trigger less activations) and at the beginning of the flow add a choice with a condition to check for the day of the week using a DataWeave expression. With the choice you can avoid executing the rest of the flow if it is not the right day.

There are no other similar flow source components that I'm aware of. You can try to create your own in Java using [Mule SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. will find another source to schedule job if not possible through this way.

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution.